# Selecting distinct records without using a temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, data-processing

I have a third party table that is being populated with some cluttered data that I'm needing to get the most recent distinct records out of. The table will be fed a new row every year, or every time the "Person" changes. The table works based on that the most recent ActiveDate is the correct person. I've created a mock table and data to show this.

```
CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
  `PersonId` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ActiveDate` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `ExpireDate` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Position` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
```

And some mock data:

```
Id       |`Name`        |ActiveDate              |ExpireDate             |Job       |`Position`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
J1234    |Doe, John     |2010-08-15 00:00:00     |2011-08-15 00:00:00    |Worker    |Janitor
J1234    |Doe, John     |2011-08-15 00:00:00     |0000-00-00 00:00:00    |Worker    |Janitor
777      |Doe, Jane     |2010-06-04 00:00:00     |0000-00-00 00:00:00    |Boss      |Janitor
777      |Doe, Jane     |2011-04-30 00:00:00     |0000-00-00 00:00:00    |Boss      |Janitor
654G     |Smith, Jane   |2011-01-20 00:00:00     |0000-00-00 00:00:00    |Worker    |Janitor
```

The table also has and ExpireDate column which is actually set by the end user, and is not always set much to my dismay. Currently I'm using a dummy table to pull the distinct records out into and store for the day. I would use a temporary table but I'm not 100% sure how to in MySQL, plus I dislike them. The way I'm doing it is just temporary in hope for better SQL.

The data then has to be joined with a multitude of other tables to get the finished product. But I'm still needing to deal with the initial set of distinct data. And joining in the other table right from the start just wont work.

So here is how I'm pulling my data, storing it, and then pulling it again later and joing it to other tables:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_Person (Id, `Name`, Job, `Position`) 
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, `Name`, Job, `Position`
    FROM Person 

SELECT  tmp_Person.Id, 
    tmp_Person.`Name`, 
    tmp_Person.Job, 
    tmp_Person.`Position`,
    Pricing.Cost, 
    Pricing.Benefit

    FROM tmp_Person
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing AS CL ON CL.PersonId = tmp_Person.Id 
        AND CL.PriceScredule = 'Major-Client' 
        AND CL.ExpireDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing AS Inter ON Inter.PersonId = tmp_Person.Id 
        AND Inter.PriceScredule = 'Internal-Client' 
        AND Inter.ExpireDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

How can I write this to avoid the cost of processing out the duplicate rows using a temporary table (in any form)? HOpefully I've made this clear enough, if not I can gladly add, or clarify.

Comment: Is it possible to have two rows with same `Id` but differ in `Name` or `Job` or `Position`? If not, the query may be more optimized.

Comment: No, the Id is actually a unique column in my data. It is for this other database too, just not in this data. I'm mining data out data from a 3rd party billing system where they just send us this never ending stream of data daily. I then fish thru and pull out what we need. I'm trying to maintain a legacy system filled with oddities, with data from a third party that is full of lots more oddities. All with my code which is hopefully...not an oddity.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't join the `Pricing` table twice, for you would then be allowed to use the `Pricing` alias (provided it wouldn't be changed). As it is, you cannot reference `Pricing` in the SELECT clause, it should be either `CL` or `Inter`.

Comment: I believe the combined condition for a single-join version could be `Pricing.PersonId = tmp_Person.Id AND Pricing.PriceScredule IN ('Major-Client', 'Internal-Client') AND Pricing.ExpireDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

Comment: You say "the most recent ActiveDate is the correct person", so why aren't you inserting just these records into your temp table? In other words, are you sure that taking the distinct records gives you the same result?

Comment: @onedaywhen, The data is mock first off, so don't get tied down to Persons being the real deal like a person table would be normally. This is actually billing info, like part numbers in a way. The part numbers age and each year there is a ton of other data from what I can see that ties the new row in. But you hit the nail on the head, I need better SQL. Something to get the most recent rows with out having to pull it into the application and pre-process it there.

Comment: @Andriy it has multiple joins because it's pricing data where each price has a new row. These are tied down by name i.e. Major-Client. Each name is a predefined, set in stone, price schedule. So the multiple joins are allowing me to capture these different rows as individual columns for processing into another database. If there is a better way I'll try it though. Again, looking for better SQL.

Comment: @Tim: I suggest you post a different question with: 1.samples of the external data you have. 2.samples of what results you want to be extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `tmp_Person` with the code you have for the temp table:

```
SELECT  tmp_Person.Id, 
    tmp_Person.`Name`, 
    tmp_Person.Job, 
    tmp_Person.`Position`,
    CL.Cost     AS MajorCost,              
    CL.Benefit  AS MajorBenefit,   
    Inter.Cost    AS InternalCost,
    Inter.Benefit AS InternalBenefit

    FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT Id, `Name`, Job, `Position`
        FROM Person 
      )
      AS tmp_Person
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing AS CL ON CL.PersonId = tmp_Person.Id 
        AND CL.PriceScredule = 'Major-Client' 
        AND CL.ExpireDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Pricing AS Inter ON Inter.PersonId = tmp_Person.Id 
        AND Inter.PriceScredule = 'Internal-Client' 
        AND Inter.ExpireDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

As @Andriy spotted, using `Pricing.Cost` or `Pricing.Benefit` in the SELECT list would raise error. I guess you forgot to change it when you posted.

Comment: I will be trying this first off in the morning. It's sure to save much more time. Even more as the database ages (hopefully gracefully).

Comment: You are replicating the OP's error by referencing `Pricing` instead of either `CL` or `Inter` (in the SELECT clause).

Comment: @Andriy: Thnx, hadn't noticed that.

Comment: @Andriy M: makes a good point. Think: why outer join to two tables yet not use their columns in the `SELECT` clause (or anywhere else)?

Comment: @onedaywhen: He was probbaly trying to simplify the query for posting here. I can understand that by having seen queries posted with tens of columns in the SELECT list.

Comment: @Andriy you are correct I did ref the wrong table names in my query.

Comment: That is perfect. I quickly modified my query and turned into into a single shot like above rather than 3 operations and it's working perfect. My 153 line query is executing in around a second, rather than many seconds and extra work rebuilding tables. Not to mention no longer having to support yet another "temp" table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Put this together before I realised the question was for mysql but the principal should be the same, this will get you the record for each PersonID with the most recent ActiveDate from Person table.

```
select *
from
(
 select persons.*, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by personid order by personid, activedate desc) as rn 
 from persons
) basedata
where basedata.rn=1
```

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL has no `ROW_NUMBER()` and no `OVER()`. No analytic functions at all.